# (CS50P) check50 returns errors to my test code, that I`m sure is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50

I have a working variant of the "Working 9 to 5" problem and a test file, that passes all the assertions. I am pretty sure, that I have tested everything, but check50 still returns me this message:

```
:) working.py and test_working.py exist
:) working.py does not import libraries other than sys and re
:) working.py converts "9 AM to 5 PM" to "09:00 to 17:00"
:) working.py converts "9:00 AM to 5:00 PM" to "09:00 to 17:00"
:) working.py converts "8 PM to 8 AM" to "20:00 to 08:00"
:) working.py converts "8:00 PM to 8:00 AM" to "20:00 to 08:00"
:) working.py converts "12 AM to 12 PM" to "00:00 to 12:00"
:) working.py converts "12:00 AM to 12:00 PM" to "00:00 to 12:00"
:) working.py raises ValueError when given "8:60 AM to 4:60 PM"
:) working.py raises ValueError when given "9AM to 5PM"
:) working.py raises ValueError when given "09:00 to 17:00"
:) working.py raises ValueError when given "9 AM - 5 PM"
:) working.py raises ValueError when given "10:7 AM - 5:1 PM"
:) correct working.py passes all test_working checks
:( test_working.py catches working.py printing incorrect hours
    expected exit code 1, not 2
:( test_working.py catches working.py printing incorrect minutes
    expected exit code 1, not 2
:( test_working.py catches working.py not raising ValueError when user omits " to "
    expected exit code 1, not 2
:( test_working.py catches working.py not raising ValueError for out-of-range times
    expected exit code 1, not 2
:( test_working.py catches working.py not raising ValueError for invalid time format
    expected exit code 1, not 2
```

Here`s the test file:

```
from working import convert
import pytest

def test_wrong_hour():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("13 AM to 5 PM")

def test_wrong_minute():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("12:60 AM to 5 PM")


def test_time():
    assert convert("9 AM to 5 PM") == "09:00 to 17:00"
    assert convert("9:30 AM to 5:45 PM") == "09:30 to 17:45"


def test_to():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("9 AM 5 PM")


def test_format():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("9 to 5")
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("17:00 to 9 PM")


test_wrong_hour()
test_wrong_minute()
test_time()
test_to()
test_format()
```

I have even tried looking at a YouTube video with the solution. I did not copy it line by line, but have basically done the same thing at the end as that video said. It still returns me this message and I cannot figure out why it does so. Has any of you taken the CS50P course and had this issue? If so, do you know the solution?

Comment: Note that the failures are all related to `test_working.py`, not `working.py`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

for the last two errors you should include these functions in the test_working.py file:

```
def test_wrong_format():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("9 AM - 9 PM")


def test_wrong_minute():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
         convert("9:60 AM to 9:60 PM")


def test_wrong_hour():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        convert("13 PM to 17 PM")
```

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pytest documentation][1]
to test something you just need to make the function starts with test_ or _test, no need to call the function in the end. Even though pytest is working fine as though you call the function, check50 doesn't like that

Erase this section from your code, and you should be fine.

```
test_wrong_hour()
test_wrong_minute()
test_time()
test_to()
test_format()
```

Also, is it okay for you to share the answer to the world???
[1]: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/

Comment: Thank you so much! Also now I feel stupid for sharing the answers as you pointed out (thanks fot that, btw, i never thought about it). I`ll try to delete the answer to the problem immediately.